# Electronjs + react: @electron/remote is disabled for this WebContents

Tags: reactjs, build, electron, electron-builder

So this error is `@electron/remote is disabled for this WebContents. Call require("@electron/remote/main").enable(webContents) to enable it.`
This only happens when I build the app, not in testing.

Also I don't know if this is a part of the problem but I get this message in the console after building:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled with warnings.

File sizes after gzip:

  109.04 kB  build\static\js\main.6351be2a.js
  29.09 kB   build\static\css\main.b2a80ea4.css

The project was built assuming it is hosted at ./.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:

  https://cra.link/deployment

'electron-builder' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I tried this (main.js):

```
const { initialize, enable } = require('@electron/remote/main')
initialize();
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    // Create the browser window.
    const window = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: true,
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })

    enable(window.webContents);
```

But the error persists? This seems like the solution they want so I'm just not sure what to do.

Here is what my render (index.js) looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';


import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import App from './frontend/App';

import '@fontsource/roboto/300.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/400.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/500.css';
import '@fontsource/roboto/700.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set `nodeIntegration: false` (since I'm not using nodeIntegration) and then `nodeIntegrationInWorker: true` since that is for the preload.js to still work.
Also for the electron-builder I needed to switch to yarn and reinstall electron-builder and add this to my package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "21.2.0"
  },
```